# How to add image overlay to Product image?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, catalog, product-list

I am trying to add an overlay for products the have sold out but for some reason my implementation isn't working...

I have created an .png file and a CSS class for the overlay.

```
.products-overlay {
    position:absolute;
    left:0%;
    top:0%;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
    border:none!important;
}
```

I've add an IF condition inside of the list.phtml file

```
        <?php // Product Image ?>
        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(220); ?>" width="220" height="220" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
        <?php else: ?>
        <div class="product-image">
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(220); ?>" width="220" height="220" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                <span class="products-overlay"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/image.png') ?>" style="border: none;"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php // Product description ?>
```

Not having any Joy as the .png wont show on top of the product image.

Has anyone done something like this before?

Comment: you got out of stock products at listing of catalog?

Comment: @Keyul Shah yes I have set one product to out of stock, the div is showing with the opacity but no image...

Comment: then this is your css prb do you have live site or local if live then please share with me

Comment: @Keyul Shah sorry its localhost, what could it be though??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below solutions works for adding an overlay to product image in list.phtml file...

CSS

```
.products-overlay {
    position:absolute;
    left:0%;
    top:0%;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
    border:none!important;
}
```

list.phtml

```
<?php // Product Image ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(220); ?>" width="220" height="220" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="product-image">
    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(220); ?>" width="220" height="220" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
        <span class="products-overlay"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/image.png') ?>" style="border: none;"></span>
    </a>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php // Product description ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have change the code for you and also make sure that the image should coming or not in fire bug. and set the css

```
   <?php // Product Image ?>
    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(220); ?>" width="220" height="220" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
      <div class="products-sold-out"> </div>
        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(220); ?>" width="220" height="220" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
    </div>
        <?php // Product description ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added a screen shot of what it looks like...

Comment: Do you want same or diff look?

Comment: I edit my code please change in ur file .and check and set gae this is not code issue just css

Comment: yes its certaily CSS issue which should be quite simple but still the div won't wrap!

Comment: With out access ur browser I can't help you more

Comment: R u developer? Then this is v v small issue. You easily solve this using crome dev tool